# Quando instanciar os ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou revisando algumas abordagens de programação e cai em um dilema com relação a onde devemos instanciar nossas propriedades de navegação do `EF` `ICollection`.

Muitos casos vejo que o pessoal instancia elas no construtor, isso seria uma boa pratica?

Em poucos casos vejo exemplos que instanciam somente quando realmente necessário, o que ao meu ver seria uma abordagem mais correta.

Então, tendo o exemplo a entidade `Pais` que tem uma lista de `Estados`

Entidade Pais

```
[Table("Paises")]
[DisplayColumn("Nome")]
public class Pais : Entidade
{
    public Pais()
    {
        Estados = new HashSet<Estado>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string Sigla { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Estado> Estados { get; set; }
}
```

Entidade estado

```
[Table("Estados")]
    [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    public class Estado : Entidade
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid EstadoId { get; set; }

        public Guid PaisId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public String Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public String Sigla { get; set; }

        public virtual Pais Pais { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Cidade> Cidades { get; set; }
    }
```

Na primeira abordagem vejo no construtor de pais a criação de um `HashSet`

```
public Pais()
{
    Estados = new HashSet<Estado>();
}
```

Em outra abordagem vejo somente na hora do uso, como mostra o exemplo a seguir

```
pais = new Pais();
if (pais.Estados == null)
    pais.Estados = new List<Estado>();

pais.Estados.Add(new Estado() { Sigla = "RS", Nome = "Rio Grande do Sul" });
```

Sendo que nesse segundo caso, se a criação do `ICollection<Estado>` estivesse na entidade `Pais`, não seria necessário o `if` para verificar se o objecto `Estados` é nulo, bastando somente adicionar mais itens na coleção.

Comment: Eu ia comentar que era muita coincidência ter falado sobre isso e ler essa pergunta hoje, rs.

Comment: Achei pertinente o questionamento, por isso trouxe pra cá

Comment: Com certeza é. É uma pergunta muito boa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que o melhor é a seguinte abordagem de verificar se está nulo. Eu não costumo instanciar coleções como na primeira abordagem.

1. Em algum local no fluxo do programa pode fazer com que o estado da propriedade "Estados" fique nulo. Você pode garantir que isso não vá acontecer?
2. Por exemplo se você utilizar o [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) ele vai te sugerir para verificar por nulo.
3. Se nem sempre for usar, não tem porque alocar espaço para a coleção.
4. Com o Entity Framework, se você utiliza Include(), ou Lazy Loading não tem porque instanciar "Estados" no construtor de País.
5. Ainda com Entity Framework, em um escopo separado, você pode criar uma instância de Estado, apenas passar o código do país e adicionar ao banco de dados sem adicionar dentro da coleção de países.